# Numpy: stack array by the last dimension

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

Suppose I have 3 numpy arrays `a`, `b`, `c`, of the same shape, say

```
a.shape == b.shape == c.shape == (7,9)
```

Now I'd like to create a 3-dimensional array of size `(7,9,3)`, say `x`, such that

```
x[:,:,0] == a
x[:,:,1] == b
x[:,:,2] == c
```

What is the "pythonic" way of doing it (perhaps in one line)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: same question, tried np.tile and np.repeat. neither working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a function that does exactly that: [`numpy.dstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) ("d" for "depth"). For example:

```
In [10]: import numpy as np

In [11]: a = np.ones((7, 9))

In [12]: b = a * 2

In [13]: c = a * 3

In [15]: x = np.dstack((a, b, c))

In [16]: x.shape
Out[16]: (7, 9, 3)

In [17]: (x[:, :, 0] == a).all()
Out[17]: True

In [18]: (x[:, :, 1] == b).all()
Out[18]: True

In [19]: (x[:, :, 2] == c).all()
Out[19]: True
```

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:**

Use `numpy.stack` ([docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html#numpy.stack)), which joins a sequence of arrays along a new axis of your choice.

---

Although @NPE answer is very good and cover many cases, there are some scenarios in which `numpy.dstack` isn't the right choice (I've just found that out while trying to use it). That's because `numpy.dstack`, according to the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html):

> Stacks arrays in sequence depth wise (along third axis).
>
> This is equivalent to concatenation along the third axis after 2-D
> arrays of shape (M,N) have been reshaped to (M,N,1) and 1-D arrays of
> shape (N,) have been reshaped to (1,N,1).

Let's walk through an example in which this function isn't desirable. Suppose you have a list with 512 numpy arrays of shape `(3, 3, 3)` and want to stack them in order to get a new array of shape `(3, 3, 3, 512)`. In my case, those 512 arrays were filters of a 2D-convolutional layer. If you use `numpy.dstack`:

```
>>> len(arrays_list)
512
>>> arrays_list[0].shape
(3, 3, 3)
>>> numpy.dstack(arrays_list).shape
(3, 3, 1536)
```

That's because `numpy.dstack` always stacks the arrays along the third axis! Alternatively, you should use `numpy.stack` ([docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html#numpy.stack)), which joins a sequence of arrays along a new axis of your choice:

```
>>> numpy.stack(arrays_list, axis=-1).shape
(3, 3, 3, 512)
```

In my case, I passed -1 to the `axis` parameter because I wanted the arrays stacked along the last axis.